# What's the difference between preview mode and production mode in LUIS?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I am building an application using microsoft's [LUIS](http://www.luis.ai), but I am quite confused about the "go to preview" button and "back to production" button. It seems that there is no difference between the preview mode and the production mode. Anyone knows the difference?

[image]
[image]

Comment: The option. as of last week of November 2016, has been removed. All options of Preview are available in Production

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Intents/Actions, there are new features in **preview** you can use to fulfill the actions that were triggered through a set of channels. For example, if you created the "GetWeather" intent and the action has been triggered (all the required parameters were filled), you can use the GetCurrentWeather channel to retrieve the weather for your users to see.

More examples and information here https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/luis-api/documentation/getstartedwithluis-advanced#action-fulfillment-preview